# REGEX with look ahead and look behinds

Tags: regex

I want to write a single regex that will capture everything but company suffices (just LTD in the examples - I know how to extend this)
For example:

```
ABC            capture ABC
ABC LTD        capture ABC
ABC LTD UK     capture ABC UK
LTD ABC        capture ABC
LTD UK ABC     capture UK ABC
```

I'm working in a JAVA based environment.
So far I have `(^.*?)(?=(?:LTD|LIMITED\s*)+)` which only work for ABC LTD (not even for ABC)
Any help here would be massively appreciated.

Comment: Which language, tool are you running?

Comment: it's an inhouse one which uses java syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(?!LTD|LIMITED)\b\w+\b
```

Try this.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/zR2tR4/4

Comment: actually on closer inspections this doesn't work in the ABC LTD UK case nor the LTD UK ABC case

Comment: I did check - I see that it's highlighting all the words I want, but this wasn't capturing them. I think putting (\b\w+\b) might solve the issue though

Answer (score -1):

Don't know Java syntax exactly, but I sure that it has own replace and split commands.
Think it's much more efficient to remove company abbrevation an then split.

Code will be in C# but i think it's not much hard to move it to Java

```
// it's not univesal but matches your sample
string newString = Regex.Replace(baseString, "((LTD)|(LIMITED)|(JSC)...)",""); // remove all abbrevations without headache about Look-Forward-Back-And-So-On
string[] companyNames = newString.Split("\n");
```

Anyway - doing something with regex - try to simplify it and avoid extended features.

Comment: You don't need to use all these groups, you can remove them or only keep the main group and add word boundaries.

Comment: ((LTD)|(LIMITED)|(JSC)) != (LTD|LIMITED|JSC)

Comment: Some of engines, for example .Net with some options will treat (LTD|LIMITED|JSC) as (LT(D|L)IMITE(D|J)SC) (because it treats all tokens as independent), so it's clear to use explicit grouping it think

Comment: What options are you speaking about?